# Skype directly goes to play google

Tags: java, android, eclipse, message, skype

I have a code to msg someone through skype, the problem is, I don't know how to set it to go to the application, it directly goes to https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.skype.raider .. can anyone help?

```
skypeuser.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                   if (uri.contains("https://www.skype.com/" )) {
                        String username = "username";
                        String uri1 = "skype://Page/" + username;
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri1));
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        String uri1 = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.skype.raider";
                        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri1));
                        startActivity(i);
                    } 
                } 
            });
```

Comment: use skype package in intent for open skype application directly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27054398/1777090 your question. answer covers this

Comment: Can you tell me how to code it? Please! :)

Comment: @Tina are you a developer/programmer ?